# Displaying multi-dimensional array in a table structure in php smarty

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array, smarty

I am new to smarty. I have referred many pages to display the array values based on the id. Can anyone please help for me. The "personalDetailsDisplay"  array is,

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => AAA
            [Ref] => 5
            [Price] => 500
        )
[2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => BBB
            [Ref] => 10
            [Price] => 200
        )


)
```

In this the index is 'Id' of the person. I will get it from another loop.

I have a separate div to hold the each details separately.

No problem on displaying the div details but the problem is the content to display.

Here is the code for the content.

```
             {foreach item="viewregisterDetail" from=$viewregisterDetail }

                   {foreach from=$personalDetailsDisplay item=table}

            {foreach from=$table item=zid}
                <tr>    
                    <td>{$zid.$viewregisterDetail->getId().Name}</td>
                    <td>{$zid.$viewregisterDetail->getId().Ref}</td>
                </tr>
            {/foreach}

        {/foreach}

            {/foreach}
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the solution you want.

In PHP:

```
$viewregisterDetail = array();
$viewregisterDetail[0]['id'] = 1;
$viewregisterDetail[1]['id'] = 3;


$personalDetailsDisplay = array();

$personalDetailsDisplay[1]['Name'] = 'AAA';                 
$personalDetailsDisplay[1]['Ref'] = 5;
$personalDetailsDisplay[1]['Price'] = 500;
$personalDetailsDisplay[2]['Name'] = 'BBB';
$personalDetailsDisplay[2]['Ref'] = 10;
$personalDetailsDisplay[2]['Price'] = 200;
$personalDetailsDisplay[3]['Name'] = 'CCC';
$personalDetailsDisplay[3]['Ref'] = 100;
$personalDetailsDisplay[3]['Price'] = 900;


$smarty->assign('personalDetailsDisplay',$personalDetailsDisplay);

$smarty->assign('viewregisterDetail',$viewregisterDetail );
```

In Smarty:

```
<table>
   {foreach $viewregisterDetail  as $rdetails}
         <tr>    
            <td>{$personalDetailsDisplay[$rdetails.id].Name}</td>                                
            <td>{$personalDetailsDisplay[$rdetails.id].Ref}</td>                                
        </tr>

    {/foreach}

</table>
```

If not you need to show more your data and tell what's viewregisterDetail is and show code for this class.